# Library for upload image from gallery or camera capture in android

Tags: android, camera, image-upload

Are there some good libraries for upload option for an image form gallery or a new camera capture in android. And that can upload the image to a url on a separate thread.

Comment: `Volley` didn't tried but heard that its good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this below..This will be useful when the device is low and size of the image is large.

http://www.webspeaks.in/2012/08/upload-files-from-android-to-server.html

Upload an image or an file in **multipart** entity.

Comment: Hi, the link is broken.